# For $S = \{ \frac{4x}{x+1} | x \in \mathbb{R}, x \geq 1 \}$ bdd? g.l.b.S? l.u.b.S?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $S = \{ \frac{4x}{x+1} | x \in \mathbb{R}, x \geq 1 \}$

Is S bounded? Find g.l.b. S and the l.u.b. S if they exist. Give justification, formal proof not necessary. (Based on Calculus)

I did not justify my answers for this, but i knew the glb S = 2
and lub S = DNE.

I also said based off calculus that because 4x is faster than x+1 that it is unbounded above.

Comment: Can you find a point $x\geq 1$ where $\frac{4x}{x+1}\geq 5$?

Comment: (Also, a related hint: what is $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{4x}{x+1}$?  I think you'll find that it is not, in fact, unbounded above.  An even more explicit hint: since $x$ is positive, $\frac{4x}{x+1}\leq \frac{4x}{x+1}+\frac{4}{x+1}$.  Can you find a way to simplify the RHS there?)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{4x}{x+1}=4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write $\frac{4x}{x+1}=\frac{4}{1+\frac{1}{x}}$, then on the interval $[0,\infty)$, the set $S$ is bounded below by zero and bounded above by four.